# Excel SQL command to retrieve specific information from access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with importing data from Microsoft Access to Excel with sql command. I use "ADODB" to connect Excel with Access.
I have a few tables in Access. I want to get the ClientDesc and ProductDesc when I input on TrackNo and with a command button to run the command. I tried it with inner join (incomplete, without ProductTB), but i only get the first row of information.

So how can I get all the respective/required info (ClientDesc and ProductDesc)?

Below is my current code of the Excel module.

```
Option Explicit
Public Const DBLink As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mother File.accdb;"

Public Sub SearchTrack(asd As String)

Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset    
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset   

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
CN.Open DBLink

 Set Rs = CN.Execute("select MotherTb.Customer, ClientTb.ClientDesc from MotherTb inner join ClientTb on Mother.Customer = ClientTb.ClientID")

 If Not Rs.EOF Then
    Cells(2, 2) = Rs("ClientDesc")
Else
    MsgBox "Record not found"
End If

Set Rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Attached with
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JX2y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through your recordset:

```
i = 2
Do While Not Rs.EOF 
    Cells(i, 2) = Rs("Customer")
    Cells(i, 3) = Rs("ClientDesc")

    i = i + 1
    Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Alternatively, if memory allows, use the Excel method: [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx)

```
Cells(2,2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
```

Comment: Im sorry, i still couldn't get it work. The aim is to get the relevant description from other table based on the value in MotherTb. Im sorry, im new into vba.

Comment: That's an SQL query problem not VBA. Please edit your post to show relevant tables and fields to build query statement in recordset call.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused, post edited, attached with sample.

Answer (score -1):

I've had to use the .MoveLast followed by a .MoveFirst on the recordset, before looping, to bring in multiple rows.